# progress bar in WebView using kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, progress-bar

i'm using this code to show a progress bar while whiting the url to load in the WebView but the app is crashing after few seconds from the starting of the webview page and it give me the Error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is
>   null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull,
>   parameter favicon

```
  val progressBar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.prg)
    val url: String = intent.getStringExtra("targetURL") ?: ""


    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            view.visibility =View.INVISIBLE
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            view.visibility =View.VISIBLE
            progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }

    }
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

    val settings = webView.settings
    settings.domStorageEnabled = true

    webView.loadUrl(url)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the `favicon` nullable.

Change

```
favicon: Bitmap
```

To

```
favicon: Bitmap?
```